# How to use .each() inside for loop with list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, django

I have a list I am trying to iterate over to change each div into a song of its own. The list I have is simplified by JSON because the data comes from a Django queryset. My problem is that I can't figure out how to continue to
the next object without having it repeat the same one within the loop.

I have tried setting variables outisde to stop it or go to the next song without success.

```
The Json as data variable:  [{"song":{"file":"music/the_unlighteds_2.mp3"}},{"song":{"file":"music/the_unlighted_6_32.mp3"}}]
```

```
Script code:

 <script>



        $("h1[id]").each(function(){

            var next_song = "";
            var data = [{{ chap_song|safe }}]
            console.log(data);
            for (var i in data) {

            var next_song = JSON.stringify(data[i].song.file);


            }
            console.log(next_song);
            if(this.id==='scroll-to')$(this).html("<audio controls autoplay> <source src=https://theunlighted.io/media/"+next_song.replace(/\"/g, "")+ " type=\"audio/wav\"></audio>");

});


 </script>
```

[image: My result ends up like so]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the same loop index to access the data in both arrays.

```
var data = [{{ chap_song|safe }}];
$("h1[id]").each(function(i){ // i is the index of the current h1
  var song = data[i]; // so we want the corresponding song
  $(this).html("<audio controls autoplay> <source src=https://theunlighted.io/media/"+song.file.replace(/\"/g, "")+ " type=\"audio/wav\"></audio>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("h1[id]").each(function(index){
            var next_song = [];
            var data = [{"song":{"file":"music/the_unlighteds_2.mp3"}},{"song":{"file":"music/the_unlighted_6_32.mp3"}}]
            console.log(data);
            for (var i in data) {

            next_song.push(JSON.stringify(data[i].song.file));


            }
            console.log(next_song[index]);
            if(this.id==='scroll-to')$(this).html("<audio controls autoplay> <source src=https://theunlighted.io/media/"+next_song[index].replace(/\"/g, "")+ " type=\"audio/wav\"></audio>");

});
```

I have never used jquery, but it is described according to your needs. You can try my way of writing